# Making a variable proper for analysis

Tags: spss, data-analysis

I have a string variable in this format:

```
stock
stockA
stockB
stockC
```

I would to use this variable as grouping variable in discriminant analysis but I can see this in list. There a way to select all the column in spss and use tranform to make a new column which makes this variable avaliable for analysis.

But what should I choose from transformation in order to make it?

It is from transform or data table.
It is something like

```
stockA -> A
stockB -> B
stockC -> C
```

It is from tranform -> record to different values but what exactly should I do?

**Answer** (**with problem**):

**Transform** -> **Recode into Different Variables**

In **output variable** I set a **Name** and a **Label**:

I click the button **Old and New Values**..

In the column **Old Value** -> **Value** I insert the old value and in **New Value** -> **Value** and I press the button **Add**

When I finishe I press all **ok** and I can see the new column in SPSS

When I go to make a factor analysis I can see the new variable from the previous action.

However when I go to Analyze -> Classify -> Discriminant Analysis I can't see the new variable.

Why? How can I make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recode it into a numeric variable.  Use AUTORECODE (Transform > Automatic Recode)